# Showing a Chebyshev set

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization, chebyshev-polynomials

I want to show that $\{1,e^{ix},...,e^{(n-1)x} \}$ is a Chebyshev Set on $(0,2\pi]$. Now I know that $\{1,x,...,x^n \}$ is one and that $e^{ix}$ is injective on $(0,2\pi]$. But how do I show that if I have a map
$$
m:(0,2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C} , x\rightarrow e^{ix}
$$
that the Polynomial
$$
a_0+a_1\cdot e^x + ... + a_n \cdot e^{ix^n}
$$
has max. the same number of zeroes than
$$
a_0+a_1\cdot x + ... + a_n \cdot x^n
$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-zero polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k$ has at most $n$ roots on any subset of $z\in \mathbb C$ including the circle $z=e^{ix}, x\in(0,2\pi]$ corresponding to at most $n$ distinct values of $x$ that produce such roots. That is, the polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k e^{ixk}$ has at most $n$ roots on the interval $x\in(0,2\pi]$.